# ASP.NET Core 7 Web API with OpenTelemetry error : "'AspNetCoreInstrumentationOptions' does not contain a definition for 'Enrich'"

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-7.0, open-telemetry

I have a Jaeger/OpenTelemetry instrumentation configured and it is generating traces well. When I try to *access the trace context manually* and assign it to some custom variables I am getting an error:

> 'AspNetCoreInstrumentationOptions' does not contain a definition for 'Enrich' and no accessible extension method 'Enrich' accepting a first argument of type 'AspNetCoreInstrumentationOptions' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

My goal is to extract the `Activity.TraceId` and `Activity.SpanId` from the following trace that is generated when I make a call :

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
  Now listening on: http://localhost:80
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\xxx\Documents\Projects\...src    
Resource associated with Metric:
    service.name: CustomerAPI
    service.instance.id: d9fffb91-d316-4e7b-b881-933c38575de3
    telemetry.sdk.name: opentelemetry
    telemetry.sdk.language: dotnet
    telemetry.sdk.version: 1.5.0
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
Activity.TraceId:            8df367ef9b8f0bfbae7d7b72a0a3932e
Activity.SpanId:             fbd22cb616afb6b8
Activity.TraceFlags:         Recorded
Activity.ActivitySourceName: Microsoft.AspNetCore
Activity.DisplayName:        WeatherForecast
Activity.Kind:               Server
Activity.StartTime:          2023-06-28T11:35:29.0274430Z
Activity.Duration:           00:00:00.2085907
Activity.Tags:
    net.host.name: localhost
    http.method: GET
    http.scheme: http
    http.target: /weatherforecast/
    http.url: http://localhost:80/weatherforecast/
    http.flavor: 1.1
    http.user_agent: PostmanRuntime/7.32.3
    http.route: WeatherForecast
    http.status_code: 200
Resource associated with Activity:
    service.name: CustomerAPI
    service.instance.id: f63e3907-dccf-407d-9ebf-xxxxxxxxxxxx
    telemetry.sdk.name: opentelemetry
    telemetry.sdk.language: dotnet
    telemetry.sdk.version: 1.5.0
```

When I extract these two I want to assign them to a List variable defined below :

```
namespace CustomerAPI.Helpers
{
    public static class CorrelationData
    {
        public static List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Correlation { get; set; } = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
    }
}
```

To achieve this I have tried to update `.AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation()` as shown below, but that is when the error is thrown:

```
using OpenTelemetry;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Metrics;
using OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http;
using OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Jaeger;
using OpenTelemetry.Exporter;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

var appBuilder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

appBuilder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .ConfigureResource(builder => builder.AddService(serviceName: "CustomerAPI"))
    .WithTracing(builder => builder
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation(options =>
        {
            options.Filter = httpContext => true;
            options.Enrich = activity =>
            {
                // Extract trace information
                var traceId = activity.TraceId;
                var spanId = activity.SpanId;

                // Add trace information to the Correlation list
                CorrelationData.Correlation.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Activity.TraceId", traceId.ToHexString()));
                CorrelationData.Correlation.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Activity.SpanId", spanId.ToHexString()));

                return;
            };
        })
        .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
        .AddConsoleExporter()
        .AddJaegerExporter(o =>
        {
            o.AgentHost = "localhost";
            o.AgentPort = 6831;
            o.Endpoint = new Uri("localhost:14268");
            o.Protocol = JaegerExportProtocol.UdpCompactThrift;
        }))
    .WithMetrics(builder => builder.AddConsoleExporter());
    
appBuilder.Services.AddControllers();
appBuilder.Services.AddHttpClient();

appBuilder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
```

What am I missing ?

Is there a direct way of accessing the actual trace data that has been generated.

Comment: Shouldn't you be using `EnrichWithHttpRequest`, `EnrichWithHttpResponse` or `EnrichWithException`? (according to [the docs](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-dotnet/blob/main/src/OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.AspNetCore/README.md#enrich))

Comment: Correct I have added  EnrichWithHttpRequest

Comment: Moral of this story: read the docs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct method to use is `EnrichWithHttpRequest` as below :

```
using OpenTelemetry;
using OpenTelemetry.Trace;
using OpenTelemetry.Resources;
using OpenTelemetry.Metrics;
using OpenTelemetry.Instrumentation.Http;
using OpenTelemetry.Exporter.Jaeger;
using OpenTelemetry.Exporter;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using CustomerAPI.Helpers;

var appBuilder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

appBuilder.Services.AddOpenTelemetry()
    .ConfigureResource(builder => builder.AddService(serviceName: "CustomerAPI"))
    .WithTracing(builder => builder
        .AddAspNetCoreInstrumentation(options =>
        {
            options.Filter = httpContext => true;
            options.EnrichWithHttpRequest = (activity, httpRequest) =>
            {
                // Extract trace information
                var traceId = activity.TraceId;
                var spanId = activity.SpanId;

                // Add trace information to the Correlation list
                CorrelationData.Correlation.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Activity.TraceId", traceId.ToHexString()));
                CorrelationData.Correlation.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Activity.SpanId", spanId.ToHexString()));

                return;
            };
        })
        .AddHttpClientInstrumentation()
        .AddConsoleExporter()
        .AddJaegerExporter(o =>
        {
            o.AgentHost = "localhost";
            o.AgentPort = 6831;
            o.Endpoint = new Uri("localhost:14268");
            o.Protocol = JaegerExportProtocol.UdpCompactThrift;
        }))
    .WithMetrics(builder => builder.AddConsoleExporter());
    
appBuilder.Services.AddControllers();
appBuilder.Services.AddHttpClient();

appBuilder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
```

And the trace data is extracted successfully as in the logs below :

```
     info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Development
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\Users\etshuma\Documents\Projects\xxx\PlatformService\src    
Resource associated with Metric:
    service.name: CustomerAPI
    service.instance.id: 8a9b2bc7-755a-4732-b02c-0a6f6f61b885
    telemetry.sdk.name: opentelemetry
    telemetry.sdk.language: dotnet
    telemetry.sdk.version: 1.5.0
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy.HttpsRedirectionMiddleware[3]
      Failed to determine the https port for redirect.
info: CustomerAPI.Controllers.WeatherForecastController[0]
      Correlation: [Activity.TraceId, 631fc5f46ec19d4ca58b0301fcf946d2], [Activity.SpanId, 17dea7f773f99dc2]   
Activity.TraceId:            631fc5f46ec19d4ca58b0301fcf946d2
Activity.SpanId:             17dea7f773f99dc2
Activity.TraceFlags:         Recorded
Activity.ActivitySourceName: Microsoft.AspNetCore
Activity.DisplayName:        WeatherForecast
Activity.Kind:               Server
Activity.StartTime:          2023-06-28T13:09:03.3373125Z
Activity.Duration:           00:00:00.1933796
Activity.Tags:
    net.host.name: localhost
    service.instance.id: 67cafdae-60c5-4ba8-962b-4ade8d70b021
    telemetry.sdk.name: opentelemetry
    telemetry.sdk.language: dotnet
    telemetry.sdk.version: 1.5.0
```

This from a logger I injected into one of the endpoints :

```
 [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
{
    _logger.LogInformation("Correlation: {@Correlation}", CorrelationData.Correlation);

    return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
    {
        Date = DateOnly.FromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddDays(index)),
        TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
        Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
    })
    .ToArray();
}
```